# Error 500 without logs with laravel 5.1

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, laravel-5

I've just installed my Laravel app in a AWS EC2 instance.

I use Apache and PHP 5.6

When I try to access my app, I just get a 500 error without stack.

What I did:

```
- chmod 777 to storage dir
- 'debug' => true <-- in config/app.php
```

In php.ini

```
; display_errors
Default Value: On
Development Value: On
Production Value: Off

; display_startup_errors
Default Value: Off
Development Value: On
Production Value: Off

; error_reporting
Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
Development Value: E_ALL
Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

When I check the logs, I get this error

```
[Wed Dec 16 22:58:08.791244 2015] [:error] [pid 3110] [client 189.217.57.126:62532] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed openin
g required '/var/www/html/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html
/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

So yes, there is an error, but no, I can't display it....

Any Idea???

Comment: I don't know if it's a paste issue, but to set `display_errors` you need a line like `display_errors On` etc. Those 'Development Value' etc. are just examples, not how the config file should look.

Comment: ah, ok, I changed it to display_errors On, and delete the next 2 paraphers, then restart apache, but still no logs

Comment: Have you installed composer?

Comment: well, solution for this error was installing composer, this is true, but I still cannot see logs!

Comment: How do you installed laravel ?

Comment: I installed it in local, developped like 1 month, a then uploaded it to Amazon EC2

Comment: In your `.env` have you got `APP_DEBUG=true`?